# How Do I Shrink and Slide a View into the Upper-Left Corner?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a layout resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- other widget here -->

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

At a certain point in time, this layout will be shown in my activity. At that point, I will set the visibility of the `thumbnail` `ImageView` to `View.VISIBLE`, and I then want to animate it to take up 30% of the width/height of the screen, located `marginPixels` from the upper-left corner (on my test device, `marginPixels` is 48). That will expose the underlying `View`, except for the portion taken over by the `thumbnail`.

To that end, I have the following Java:

```
thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
thumbnail
  .animate()
  .scaleX(0.3f)
  .scaleY(0.3f)
  .x(marginPixels)
  .y(marginPixels)
  .setDuration(animDuration);
```

The result is that the animation happens, but `thumbnail` is centered within the `FrameLayout`.

I have tried:

- Both having and not having `android:layout_gravity="top|left"` on the `ImageView` in the layout XML
- `translationX(marginPixels)`/`translationY(marginPixels)` instead of `x(marginPixels)`/`y(marginPixels)`
- `translationXBy(marginPixels)`/`translationYBy(marginPixels)` instead of `x(marginPixels)`/`y(marginPixels)`

None seem to have an effect. The `thumbnail` is always centered. If I comment out the `x()` and `y()` calls, the result is also centered, suggesting that for some reason, they are being ignored. If, instead, I comment out the `scaleX()` and `scaleY()` calls (leaving `x()` and `y()` as shown in the original listing), the `thumbnail` is translated to the right position, but it is still full-size. If I use `setX()` and `setY()` on the `thumbnail` itself before the animation and comment out the `x()` and `y()` calls, the `thumbnail` initially is positioned at the right spot, but as soon as the scale animation kicks in, I'm back to being centered.

Now, I can certainly calculate the right value to use, given screen size and whatnot. But it would seem as though `x()`/`y()` should be the right methods to use on the `ViewPropertyAnimator`, so I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong.

**UPDATE**: This code works (or at least gets close — I haven't actually measured the results to confirm precise pixel placement):

```
int x=(int)(-0.35f*(float)bmp.getWidth())+marginPixels;
int y=(int)(-0.35f*(float)bmp.getHeight())+marginPixels;

thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);
thumbnail
  .animate()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .scaleX(0.3f)
  .scaleY(0.3f)
  .setDuration(animDuration);
```

What I do not grok is why those calculations are needed. IOW, why are the `x` and `y` contingent upon the scale?

Comment: Have you tried with `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` in the `thumbnail`?

Comment: No, wait, that's stupid; maybe the trick is in swapping the moments when you make each call? Like you did in the update, but without setting the new bitmap.

Comment: @EricBrandwein: Well, setting the new bitmap is non-negotiable -- I have to do that. Even if I get rid of the animation, and use `setX()`/`setY()`/`setScaleX()`/`setScaleY()`, I get a centered result. So, the animation results fit what the steady state gives me, and that means this doesn't feel like a timing issue to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting `scale` (either with `setScale` or through an animation), `pivot` values are being taken into account. The default values of `pivotX` and `pivotY` are half of the `width` and half of the `height` (respectively). So any scaling with default `pivots` will result in `View` being scaled from (or toward) the center of the `View` when the `scale` is `1.0f`.

`X` and `Y` (as well as `translationX` and `translationY`) are not affected by `pivots`. You can see your `thumbnail` is actually being shifted by `marginPixels` (both vertically and horizontally).

If you try the following code, you'll see that everything works as expected.

```
thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
thumbnail.setPivotX(0);
thumbnail.setPivotY(0);
thumbnail
  .animate()
  .scaleX(0.3f)
  .scaleY(0.3f)
  .x(marginPixels)
  .y(marginPixels)
  .setDuration(animDuration);
```

[image]

Comment: "X and Y (as well as translationX and translationY) are not affected by pivots" -- I would phrase this the opposite way, that X and Y are relative to the pivots. If they were not affected, then changing the pivots would not change the behavior of X and Y. That being said, your approach works and makes sense. Many thanks!

Comment: Yep I totally agree. Glad I could help :)